# Identifying a crescent-shaped thin sheet of metal that has rusted off the wheel area

Tags: toyota, brake-rotor, part-identification, matrix

I have a 2005 Matrix in a place that is too salt-happy during the winter. The following rusted off and fell out from the inner side of the front wheel -- looks like a mud guard of some sort. Is it anything I should bother replacing before winter starts?

[image: rusted off and fell out]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a dust shield (or sometimes called a backing plate) for the rotor on the disk brake system. It would cover the back side of the rotor. You would be able to see it if you got under the car and looked at the rotor from the back side. I'm not positive about this, though, as this piece is pretty mangled.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like exactly what it is. I'll ask the dealer whether they can replace it when I take the car in for service next week.  I just need the car to last one more winter. :)

Comment: @mricon ... If you are going to replace the car next year, you may want to just do without it. It helps keep the rotor clean, but is not a safety and something I wouldn't be too worried about.

Comment: Ah, good to know. It's a low-mileage car (only 80K miles), but with all the salt on the roads here, that's what ends up killing your car, not the engine.